# compare 2 variables having number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code which I am using.. Here I am getting values from form elements. Please guide me through it.. It is not giving proper result.

```
var outoff11 = document.getElementById('out_off11').value;
var acc11 = document.getElementById('acc11').value;
var temp = acc11 <= outoff11;
if(temp){
alert("True");
alert(outoff+acc);
}
    else{
            alert("False");
            alert(outoff+acc);
        }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I bet you're getting `NaN` instead of the expected result.

Comment: Based on the title of your question, I'm assuming you expect the two textfields to contain numbers.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var outoff11 = parseInt(document.getElementById('out_off11').value, 10);
var acc11 = parseInt(document.getElementById('acc11').value, 10);
```

Comment: It is working for me.. Please tell me why you have used (value,10) in the last.

Comment: Well, that's not really necessary, but it just defines the numeric system you want the integer to be parsed as (you want decimal numbers, right?). 2 stands for binary, 10 stands for decimal and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`var temp = acc11 <= outoff11;`

to

`var temp = parseInt(acc11,10) <= parseInt(outoff11,10);`

Comment: This should solve the problem, but generally, it would be best to keep the int value, for later use without similar confusion, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what he's trying to accomplish but if there are no further manipulations on this, then this should be sufficient.